# Calculating pandas rolling mean and assigning it to a new df column returns only NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1.I have the following price data and I want to calculate average volume for different periods. `data` (not indexed)

| date | ticker | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-29 | AAPL | 80819203.0 |
| 2021-03-30 | AAPL | 84778972.0 |
| 2021-03-31 | AAPL | 118323826.0 |
| 2021-04-01 | AAPL | 75089134.0 |
| 2021-04-05 | AAPL | 87551744.0 |
| 2021-04-06 | AAPL | 80171253.0 |
| 2021-04-07 | AAPL | 83466716.0 |
| 2021-04-08 | AAPL | 88844591.0 |
| 2021-04-09 | AAPL | 106686703.0 |
| 2021-04-12 | AAPL | 91419983.0 |
| 2021-04-13 | AAPL | 91266545.0 |
| 2021-04-14 | AAPL | 87222782.0 |
| 2021-04-15 | AAPL | 89347102.0 |
| 2021-04-16 | AAPL | 84922386.0 |
| 2021-04-19 | AAPL | 94264215.0 |
| 2021-04-20 | AAPL | 94812349.0 |
| 2021-04-21 | AAPL | 68847136.0 |
| 2021-04-22 | AAPL | 84566456.0 |
| 2021-04-23 | AAPL | 78756779.0 |
| 2021-04-26 | AAPL | 65335049.0 |
| 2021-04-27 | AAPL | 66015804.0 |
| 2021-04-28 | AAPL | 107760097.0 |
| 2021-04-29 | AAPL | 151100953.0 |
| 2021-04-30 | AAPL | 109839466.0 |
| 2021-05-03 | AAPL | 75135100.0 |
| 2021-05-04 | AAPL | 137564718.0 |
| 2021-05-05 | AAPL | 84000900.0 |
| 2021-05-06 | AAPL | 78128334.0 |
| 2021-05-07 | AAPL | 78973273.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | AAPL | 87457656.0 |
| 2021-05-11 | AAPL | 125668247.0 |
| 2021-05-12 | AAPL | 112172282.0 |
| 2021-05-13 | AAPL | 105861339.0 |
| 2021-05-14 | AAPL | 81163792.0 |
| 2021-05-17 | AAPL | 73810407.0 |
| 2021-05-18 | AAPL | 62455311.0 |
| 2021-05-19 | AAPL | 90595813.0 |
| 2021-05-20 | AAPL | 76857123.0 |
| 2021-05-21 | AAPL | 79295436.0 |
| 2021-05-24 | AAPL | 62823701.0 |
| 2021-05-25 | AAPL | 72009482.0 |
| 2021-05-26 | AAPL | 54464024.0 |
| 2021-05-27 | AAPL | 93505088.0 |
| 2021-05-28 | AAPL | 71311109.0 |
| 2021-06-01 | AAPL | 67637118.0 |
| 2021-06-02 | AAPL | 58847659.0 |
| 2021-06-03 | AAPL | 75331115.0 |
| 2021-06-04 | AAPL | 74505841.0 |
| 2021-06-07 | AAPL | 70340619.0 |
| 2021-06-08 | AAPL | 72754129.0 |

2.Then I create another df - `indicators` which includes only *date* and *ticker* columns (not indexed again)

```
indicators = pd.DataFrame() 

indicators['ticker'] = data['ticker']
indicators['date'] = data['date']
```

Instead of writing:

```
indicators['avg_vol_5'] = data['volume'].rolling(5).mean()
indicators['avg_vol_10'] = data['volume'].rolling(10).mean()
```

3.I created a function which should make the process look better:

```
def calcAvgs(list_periods, col_name, avg_name):
    for i in list_periods:
        indicators[avg_name + '_' + str(i)] = data[col_name].rolling(i).mean()
```

4.I enter the following data when I execute the function:

`calcAvgs([5, 10,  20, 30, 60, 90], 'volume', 'avg_vol')`

`data` is the df with the price data. `indicators` is the df where I save the indicators data.

If I just want to print the result from the calculation side `data[col_name].rolling(i).mean()`, everything looks ok. The problem is that when I assign the results to `indicators[avg_name + '_' + str(i)]` - the desired column which is created at the moment of calculation, all I get as a result are NaNs.

Any ideas on why this might happen would be appreciated.

Comment: Your function returns `None` since you didn't specify a `return`. If you assign it to a column, it will be filled with `Nans`.

Comment: OP is trying to mutate a dataframe no `return` would be expected from this function. @WholeBrain

Comment: @WholeBrain So you are saying I should return `data[col_name].rolling(i).mean()` and assign it to a column outside the func?

Comment: `Return` would not work to generate multiple columns if anything it would be `yield`. Let's not get side-tracked. Can you include samples of `indicators` and `data` to test with? As copyable code not as an image that would need transcribed manually.

Comment: Your description implies that you assign the returned values back to `indicators` outside the function. If that's the case, then you are assigning a None.

Comment: I have added volume data. `date` column is index and there is `date` column which is index in `indicators` df. The rest of the columns I add as shown in the function. They are not created in advance.

Comment: @HenryEcker The new columns can just be added to `indicators` df.

Comment: It is `data` - the one I take the values for calculation from.

Comment: Right so again, I can't add to `indicators` if I don't know what `indicators` looks like. Is it an empty frame to begin with?

Comment: No, it is not. It has date (as index) and ticker, like the `data` df.

Comment: Interesting thing is that there is no problem if I have completely empty df:
`ind = pd.DataFrame()`
`listp = [5, 10]`
`n = 'avg_3'`
`m = 'volume'`
`for i in listp:`
    `ind[n + '_' + str(i)] = data[m].rolling(i).mean()`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error I created indicators from data as it was not provided `indicators = data[['ticker']].copy(deep=True)` and the function works as expected... Will you update your question to include a block of code that can be copied directly into a clean workspace and reproduce the issue. A misalignment of indexes in the `indicators` Frame is the most likely cause of the issue and without it I cannot determine where the issue is.

Comment: @HenryEcker I have numbered my steps. My mistake, the df-s are not indexed. So `date` is a normal column.

Comment: @HenryEcker actually your comments about indexes solved my problem. I had to index both tables before running the function. I realized that the whole indexing thing happens later in my code where I need it for another reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing tables before running my function solved my problem:

```
data = data.set_index('date')
indicators.index = data.index
indicators = indicators.drop(columns = ['date'])
```